# Getting bubbles out of a print glued to glass

Tags: adhesives, paper, glass, technique-identification

I printed a picture from my computer on regular printer paper. I then put a coat of Mod Podge on a glass block and glued the picture to it, but there were bubbles in the picture. While I'm trying to get the bubbles out, the paper keeps tearing.
How can I stop that from happening; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For smaller bubbles, prick a pinhole in the bubble with a needle, then squeeze the air out of it. Bigger ones will leave an unremovable crease with this treatment.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's probably easiest to start over. Cleaning the glass and printing the picture again shouldn't be too much of a problem. You should also use a flat tool to push out air bubbles (any plastic (credit) card or a window wiper will do).

Next time, apply a slightly thicker coat of mod podge to the back of the paper than you stricktly need. The excess will help you push out air bubbles. The paper will start curling in on itself from the moisture, but give it some more time and it should straighten out again. Just take care that it cannot roll up and touch itself because that's very hard to untangle again.

Carefully pick up the prepared picture and hold it horizontally. Let only the very bottom of the paper touch the glass. Adjust it to make sure it's straight and in the desired position. Then start pushing the paper towards the glass so it starts curling upwards.

Once about one inch of the paper touches the glass, start gently pushing the excess glue and air out from under that section with a credit card or glass wiper. Make sure not to tear the paper. Push another inch of paper against the glass and push glue and air out again. Repeat this until the entire paper is glued on. Then wipe off the excess glue.

The best image I could find is in German, but I think you can understand the process. Step 3 shows you how to gradually push the paper against the glass and push air out with a tool.

[image]
[Image Source](https://www.sanier.de/holz/moebel-mit-folie-bekleben)

Comment: Use a burnisher (basically a  very rounded off stick, usually plastic, bone, or smooth wood) or a roller to push out the bubbles. A credit card may have too sharp of an edge and will scrape the paper. The burnisher or roller will not scrape and is a lot less likely to rip the paper.